# Is there any software that will analyse games offline?

Tags: analysis, software, windows

Usually I use [Lichess](https://lichess.org/paste) to analyse games, but sometimes I am offline. Is there any software with the capability of providing offline computer analysis, giving the rate of inaccuracies/mistakes/blunders and the average centipawn loss for a given game?

Comment: Only on Windows?

Comment: Yes (I am using Windows).

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options:

Paid:

- [Hiarcs Chess Explorer](http://www.hiarcs.com/pc-chess-explorer.htm)
- [ChessBase](https://en.chessbase.com/)
- [ChessOK Aquarium](https://shop.chessok.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=807)
- [Fritz](https://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/fritz_16_english)
- [Shredder](https://www.shredderchess.com/pc.html)

Free:

- [Lucas Chess](https://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com/)
- [SCID](http://scid.sourceforge.net/)
- [Arena](http://www.playwitharena.com/)

For all of the above, you should download the latest Stockfish and install it as an engine and use it for analysis, as it will likely be stronger than anything which comes by default.

I use HIARCS Chess Explorer, mainly due to the nice interface. I've heard Fritz can provide natural language analysis which could be useful for those new to chess engines.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a good free offline analysis tool (for Windows 10 only) from here

[PGN ChessBook](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgn-chessbook/)

which comes with the Stockfish analysis engine built in. 
It has some good tools for finding blunders and automatically annotating games, as described on

[Blunder check features](https://pgnchessbook.org/gamesfindblunders/)

A good free cross platform offline tool, also from SourceForge is

[ChessX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chessx/)

Which has been around for years, and personally I find its easier to use than

[Scid](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scid/)

which is the most popular because it has so many useful features.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Fritz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_(chess)) you can play agains the computer as well as go to the analysis mode, I think that you can buy it [here](https://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/fritz_16_english?ref=RF32-OET9DCF5AK&gclid=Cj0KCQiA37HhBRC8ARIsAPWoO0zUNdcrY6rScKbaWZbf4qhWnXRoj9ubBa60VjUWMaxG2RHCOdF7KfMaAgm-EALw_wcB) but you should be able to find a free version.
I hope you find this information useful. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can Fritz annotate games or only give the best line of play?